# Can I host some mail addresses in Microsoft 365 and keep the others in IMAP host?

Tags: imap, microsoft, microsoft-365

I manage a company with 200 users, all of them having IMAP mail in a cloud based hosting (not on premise); now I want to migrate some of those users on Microsoft 365, keeping the most of them on IMAP; is it possible? How can I let the dns failover to IMAP if not finding Microsoft 365 address?

Another question regarding free Microsoft Teams account, if I put my domain as a Microsoft corporate account, they are going to stop to work. Do you think is it possible to keep those free accounts and in the meanwhile to get corporate Microsoft Team for just some of the addresses?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For your email, you can configure your accepted domain in Exchange Online as an internal relay domain. This will allow you to host some mailboxes in Office 365 and some mailboxes on your IMAP server. You can open a free support case in your Office 365 tenant to get assistance with this.

For your Teams question, you can also open a free support case in your Office 365 tenant to ask them this question.